# Atlas QGIS Layer coverage

Tags: qgis, atlas

I have two layers, the first active in the atlas and the second in the table of contents. Both are related with a id "Refcat".

I want show only those actives in the atlas with their own symbology.

The first

```
$id = @atlas_featureid
```

And the second is coverage.... How to do this?

Comment: What do you mean the second is coverage?